# Can't change Hierarchical Navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm 100% new to Xamarin.

I've downloaded the sample code for https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/Hierarchical/. When I edit that code, I can't make page 1 navigate to page 3. When I replace:

```cs
async void OnNextPageButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync (new Page2 ());
}
```

With

```cs
async void OnNextPageButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync (new Page3 ());
}
```

and I debug, the "Next Page" button on page 1 still links to page 2. I've spent 1 hour trying all sorts of solutions and I'm lost. Can you help?

Comment: Try these steps, clean the solution -> delete all the bin and obj folders -> uninstall the app from the simulator -> debug again

Comment: Thanks for your help Scarnet. Where do I find all the bin and obj folders?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "clean the solution" ?

Comment: Go to the solution folder and type bin then obj in the search box

Comment: on the menu bar -- build -> clean solution

Comment: Did all of that, didn't work. I'm using the live player (debug on my phone). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I just tried it in the emulator and it worked, give it a try on an emulator it's maybe a bug in the live player. this project has proved to be producing all sort of bugs

Comment: Thx for taking the time! I just tried in emulator and it didn't work. Same behaviour as live player. Just to be sure, the file I'm editing is named Page1.cs. Is this the only file you changed to get the "Next page" button to show page 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171387/discussion-between-etienne-juneau-and-scarnet).

Comment: You should edit Page1Xaml.xaml.cs. Page1.cs is just demonstration of how to create Page1Xaml.xaml in code behind

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much! Really confused by that structure.